# chart.js AJAX laravel Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fontSize' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, chart.js

I'm trying to get chart.js data through AJAX, this returns error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fontSize' of undefined"

Tried jquery ajax, same error

Tried following this tut, tested different chartjs version, same error

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    showGraph();
});

function showGraph()
{
    {
        $.post("/data?_token="+$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        function (data)
        {
            console.log(data);
            var name = [];
            var marks = [];

            for (var i in data) {
                name.push(data[i].student_name);
                marks.push(data[i].marks);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: name,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Student Marks',
                        backgroundColor: '#49e2ff',
                        borderColor: '#46d5f1',
                        hoverBackgroundColor: '#CCCCCC',
                        hoverBorderColor: '#666666',
                        data: marks
                    }
                ]
            };
            var graphTarget = $("#graphCanvas");
            var barGraph = new Chart(graphTarget, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: chartdata
            });
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="graphCanvas" width="0" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: if I run this in its own localhost it works fine, but putting in laravel produced the error

Comment: In localhost "/data" is like "http://localhost/data" but in yoursite its like "http://www.example.com/data" and if webservice "data" is in sub directories maybe url has wrong.

Comment: .tnx for the edit, tried the lower cdn version, it produced different error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined, search and used the bundle version, no error now tnx